# Snap.svg Drag while Zoomed

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, snap.svg

When I use drag() on a scaled (zoomed) object, the object moves according to the scale, so that if for example, the scale is set to 3 -- then each 1px move of the mouse is multiplied by 3.

After 20 or so pixel moves by the mouse the behavior is completely unacceptable.

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
var g = s.g();
g.transform("scale(3)");

var rect = g.rect(20,20,40,40);
var circle = g.circle(60,150,50);

var move = function(dx,dy) {
    this.attr({
        transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
    });
}

var start = function() {
    this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
}
var stop = function() {
    console.log('finished dragging');
}

rect.drag(move, start, stop );
circle.drag(move, start, stop );
```

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mje8knLf/1/ (just drag one of the shapes)

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, we need to account for existing transformations that appear on all the outer elements.

Here is a plugin I did a while back to help with this.

The main bit is the dragMove function. We find the existing other transforms that are applied (there are 3 types of transform matrix in Snap on an element, localMatrix, diffMatrix, globalMatix), and invert it to get the matrix that we will want to apply to allow for the existing effect. (If there are some cases where diffMatrix doesn't work, take a look at globalMatrix).

Then using that, we can use y() and x() on the new drag amount, to find what it would be in the new coordinate space.

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {

    Element.prototype.altDrag = function() {
        this.drag( dragMove, dragStart, dragEnd );
        return this;
    }

    var dragStart = function ( x,y,ev ) {
            this.data('ot', this.transform().local );
    }

    var dragMove = function(dx, dy, ev, x, y) {
            var tdx, tdy;
            var snapInvMatrix = this.transform().diffMatrix.invert();
            snapInvMatrix.e = snapInvMatrix.f = 0;
            tdx = snapInvMatrix.x( dx,dy ); tdy = snapInvMatrix.y( dx,dy );
            this.transform( "t" + [ tdx, tdy ] + this.data('ot')  );

    }

    var dragEnd = function() {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: `transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx/3, dy/3]`.

Basic implementation:-

1. `Scale` is a global variable (can be a FLOAT also)
2. All `dx` and `dy` motion is divided by `Scale`

**sidenote:** all elements can be dragged out of the box. You might want to implement some movement limit around the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am using svg-pan-zoom.js for the pan and zoom for SVG, very easy to use.
And I am using snap.svg

```
var svgElement;
var panZoomPlan;
function setPanZoom(){
    svgElement = document.querySelector('svg');
    panZoomPlan = svgPanZoom(svgElement);   

    panZoomPlan.setMinZoom(0.1);
    panZoomPlan.setMaxZoom(50);
    panZoomPlan.setZoomScaleSensitivity(0.2);
    panZoomPlan.disableDblClickZoom();      
}

function set_draggable(svg_element) {
    var shape = plan.select("#" + svg_element);
    shape.drag(dragNode, dragStart, dragStop);
}

var dragStart = function() {    
    panZoomPlan.disablePan();
    panZoomPlan.disableZoom();
    this.isDragged = false;

    var node_id = this.node.id;

    this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
}       

var dragNode = function(dx,dy) {
    this.isDragged = true;
    realZoom = panZoomPlan.getSizes().realZoom;
    var rdx = dx/realZoom;
    var rdy = dy/realZoom;

    this.attr({
        transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [rdx, rdy]
    });

    event.preventDefault();
}

var dragStop = function() {
    panZoomPlan.enablePan();
    panZoomPlan.enableZoom();

    if (!this.isDragged) { 
        return;
    }

    //update scene elements data
    var node_id = this.node.id;
    Nodes_dict[node_id].x += Nodes_dict[node_id].rdx; 
    Nodes_dict[node_id].y += Nodes_dict[node_id].rdy;   
}
```

I hope this helps later users who are seeing this question.